# A problem with multiplicative persistence code

Tags: python

I wrote some code that finds multiplicative persistence numbers. It works fine for small numbers but breaks after some time and i dont know why. watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wim9WJeDTHQ if you don't know what that is.

anyway my idea was to start from a small number, say 10, and find which numbers "go to" 10 when you multiply their digits, (25 and 52). Now repeat this process (so for 25 we reach 55) until the number can't be divided to only factors smaller than 10 (55 is 5 and 11 and 11 is prime so we cant go on).

```
def search(start, steps = 0):
    """input int"""
    next = find_divider(start)
    if next == None:
        yield steps
    else:
        for new in perm_set(next):
            print(new)
            yield from search(new, steps + 1)

def find_divider(n, father = ""):
    if n == 1:
        return father
    for prime in [2,3,5,7]:
        if n % prime == 0:
            return find_divider(n/prime, father + str(prime))
    return None

def perm_set(n):
    """input string
       output int """
    # dp is a custom function for distinct permutaions (it works fine)
    perms = (p for p in dp(n)) 
    for p in perms:
        yield int(p)
    for p in multi_perm_set(n):
        yield int(p)


def multi_perm_set(n):
       """
       input: string
       output: int """
    if '2' in n and '2' in n.replace('2','',1):
        yield from perm_set(n.replace('2','',2) + '4')
    if '2' in n and '4' in n:
        yield from perm_set(n.replace('2','',1).replace('4','',1) + '8')
    if '2' in n and '3' in n:
        yield from perm_set(n.replace('2','',1).replace('3','',1) + '6')
    if '3' in n and '3' in n.replace('3','',1):
        yield from perm_set(n.replace('3','',2) + '9')
    return ()
```

find_divider finds the prime dividers smaller than 10 and returns them as a string. if there is a prime divider > 10 it returns None. 
perm_set takes a number (like 223) and yields all the distinct permutations (so 223, 232, 322 but also 43, 34, and 26, 62 because all of those numbers get to 12 when you multiply their digits.)

So when i run the program and check the numbers it finds i see that in the start it all works well but later it makes mistakes for some reason. For example I run the program with input (10,1) because 10 is already 1 step to reach single digit. and i get: 25->55: 3 steps, 52: 2 steps
which is correct. But when i run it on 8 it doesn't reach a dead end and after some thousands of numbers it starts to write wrong numbers for steps. Anyone has any idea for why? I thought maybe it has something to do with to many recursive steps. Can that be?

Edit: I made a function to test every number it finds and it turns out that it passes through all the numbers again after finishing but with step = step+1. This only happens to numbers < 10.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it starts to write wrong numbers for steps".  Could you explain more, or perhaps include some of the incorrect output?  Also, you've chosen not to include the source of the functions `find_divider` or `perm_set`: is there perhaps a problem with these?  Please edit your question to include these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. take 8 for example: find_divider returns 222 as his prime factor "father". Then perm_set function turns that into 222, 24, 42, and 8. So we search for 8 again but this time with steps = steps + 1.